# Getting error ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "31 APR 2001 in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a varchar field where dates are stored in the database where I need data from with values like **31 APR 2001** I run the following query

`select date(trim(contact_date)) from clients where date(trim(contact_date)) < '2002-03-12';`

Whenever it hits 31 APR 2001 I get the error ERROR:  **date/time field value out of range: "31 APR 2001**

Are there any workaround so that I won't get this error. Since all other dates get return perfectly.

The version of postgres I use is
 **PostgreSQL 8.1.22**

Comment: Storing dates in a column of type "date" would make this kind of error impossible. That's one reason SQL engines support columns of type "date". It's also more efficient--no need to trim and convert values on output.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are 30 days in the month of April.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to fix the incorrect dates, and in the future prevent such values from getting into the database. Alternatively if your query was being sent from an application, then your app could handle the error gracefully.

Comment: Thx,think I'll handle this in the application

Comment: I can't believe this was exactly the answer I needed and I had to come to stackoverflow to find it

Comment: @limasxgoesto0: it seems this site literally has everything now. I'm glad we were able to assist.

Answer (score 3):

there is no 31 in April month, prevent it from hitting 31 check it before query